# emails for all denied network activity using ufw

Tags: email, firewall, ufw

I have `ufw` configured to deny all incoming and outgoing traffic except input for SSH:

```
ufw default deny outgoing
ufw default deny incoming
ufw limit in ssh
```

Is it possible to get e-mails of denied traffic? Something that says/shows traffic was denied, from who, to who, what port, to port, etc...

I feel the e-mails should be digest or something because if all of a sudden there are hundreds of denies in a short amount of time, it should send one e-mail instead of hundreds.

Comment: I don't quite understand the need to lock down your system like this. It's totally crippled your system. Any emails, digest or otherwise, would be constant, and huge. Please explain.

Comment: It's a home server I use to play around with and learn on. I have a lot of ports explicitly opened like HTTP and HTTPS out so `apt` works. I want to know everything going in and out of the system that I haven't explicitly allowed.

Comment: You can just start with a simple `grep -i ufw /var/log/syslog` or `more /var/log/ufw.log` to see what you're getting into. Then, if you're convinced that you REALLY want to see all of this noise, pipe either output into a mail message.

Comment: That is what I was thinking of doing but thought maybe UFW has a built in way to do it. I can set a daily cron job to create a report and send me email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find an answer I liked so per @heynnema's advice, I am capturing what I want from `/var/log/ufw.log` and formatting into a table for e-mail.

```
echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">';
echo '<html>';
echo '<head>';
echo '<title></title>';
echo '<style>table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 2px;}</style>';
echo '</head>';
echo '<body>';
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><th>count</th><th>in or out</th><th>source IP</th><th>destination IP</th><th>source port</th><th>destination port</th></tr>';

# get all lines from yesterday
# capture the relevant data: IN, OUT, SRC, DST, SPT, and DPT
# send to awk
# get hostname for SRC and DST
# print everything as a table
sed -r "s/^$(date --date=yesterday +"%b %_d").*?\[UFW BLOCK\].*?IN=([^ ]*) OUT=([^ ]*) .*?SRC=([^ ]*) DST=([^ ]*) .*?SPT=([^ ]*) DPT=([^ ]*).*$/,\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6/;t;d" /var/log/ufw.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr |  awk -F"," '{
    inOrOut=$2==""?($3==""?"unknown":"out"):"in"

    cmd=sprintf("nslookup %s 2>/dev/null | sed -r -e \"s/^.*name = (.*)\.$/\\1/;t;d\"", $4)
    cmd | getline sourceName
    close(cmd)

    cmd=sprintf("nslookup %s 2>/dev/null | sed -r -e \"s/^.*name = (.*)\.$/\\1/;t;d\"", $5)
    cmd | getline destinationName
    close(cmd)

    printf "<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s (%s)</td><td>%s (%s)</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>\n", $1, inOrOut, $4, sourceName, $5, destinationName, $6, $7
}';

echo '</table>';
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';

echo '</body>';
echo '</html>';
```

I have a daily cron job that runs this script and sends as HTML email.

This results in a table like so:

```
| count | in or out | source IP             | destination IP        | source port | destination port |
|-------|-----------|-----------------------|-----------------------|-------------|------------------|
| 3     | out       | 192.168.1.100 (host1) | 192.168.1.101 (host2) | 100         | 400              |
| 1     | in        | 192.168.1.101 (host2) | 192.168.1.100 (host1) | 200         | 500              |
| 1     | out       | 192.168.1.100 (host1) | 192.168.1.100 (host1) | 300         | 600              |
```